# Error 403 forbidden when using React Router with Apache

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router

When I deploy my website built with React and React-router the landing page of my website works fine but when I try to navigate into my website I run into 403 forbidden response. I use Apache as an HTTP server and the general config of my server is the following :

```
  <IfModule mod_php.c>
    php_value date.timezone Europe/Brussels
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir /var/www/users/staff/*
  </IfModule>
```

For your information, the website is located under /var/www/projects

I added the following .htaccess to my project :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Despite those configurations the 403 forbidden error when navigating in pages managed by react-router. Did I miss some configurations?

Comment: did you check the permission of files and default user of the webserver?

Comment: @PS-PARSA The read permission is set for everyone. What's weird is that I am able to access the page under the / URL and all the static resources are loaded correctly. But when I try to access any other URL than / (e.g /test, /user) I have a forbidden response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the settings you have applied are not enough, You should change some parameters in apache.conf too...

open the apache main config file, Its path varies depending on your distribution, that's located in one of these locations:

```sh
1- /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
2- /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
3- /etc/httpd/httpd.conf
4- /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

look for `"AllowOverride"` parameter like the example below:

```
<Directory "/var/www/blahblah">
    
    AllowOverride All
    
</Directory>
```

And give the `"All"` value to that.

Then create a .htaccess file in the root folder of the webserver & set the following configs:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

NOTE: Before performing these things you have to enable the rewrite module, By entering the following commands you can do this:

debian base: sudo a2enmod rewrite
centos: uncomment `mod_rewrite.so` in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Finally, restart your web server... Now expected there is no anymore problem.

If you got any permission/server error take a look at the webserver logs which are located in one of these locations:

```sh
1- /var/log/httpd/
2- /var/log/apache2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I modified the .conf but run into a 500 error. Here is the apache2.conf I have :


`DocumentRoot /var/www/projects`

`<Directory "/var/www/projects/my_awesome_project/www">`
    `AllowOverride All`
`</Directory>`
`<Directory "/var/www/projects">`
     `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews`
     `AllowOverride All`
     `Order allow, deny`
     `allow from all`
`</Directory>`

First directory is for my website. Multiple projects are hosted under "/projects" directory. 
Could the second Directory entry conflict with mine and cause my troubles ?

Comment: @jérôme-fink if you want to host multiple projects, you can use VirtualHost, and another point: Order directive is deprecated and should not use that + (you have to write <Allow> PascalCase), anyway... what error message do you have in </var/log/apache/error.log>?

Comment: Here is the error message I got in the apache log :
[negotiation:error] [pid 4937] (13)Permission denied: [client 138.48.238.202:37014] AH00686: cannot read directory for multi: /var/www/projects/, referer: https://projects.info.unamur.be/lsfb-dataset/

Comment: @jérôme-fink change `Order allow, deny` to `Require all granted` in the config file and enter: `sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/projects` then restart ur webserver